# What are the fillers in the ICSI Meeting Recorder Dialog Act (MRDA) Corpus?

Tags: computational-linguistics, datasets, dialog-acts, filler

In the [ICSI Meeting Recorder Dialog Act (MRDA) Corpus](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/Speech/mr/), which label(s) correspond to the *Filler* class?

I have read a couple of article (e.g. (1)) saying there exist a widely applied classmap that maps the dialog acts onto 5 distinct classes: statements (S), questions (Q), backchannels (B), fillers (F) and disruptions (D).

However, looking at the data set official manual (2) and paper (3), I fail to see which label(s) should be regarded as fillers:

[image]

---

References:

- (1) Verbree, Daan, Rutger Rienks, and Dirk Heylen. "[Dialogue-act tagging using smart feature selection; results on multiple corpora.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=2215828925874010278&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)" Spoken Language Technology Workshop, 2006. IEEE. IEEE, 2006.
  APA
- (2) Dhillon, Rajdip, et al. [Meeting recorder project: Dialog act labeling guide](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=14701314755480463137&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22). No. ICSI-TR-04-002. INTERNATIONAL COMPUTER SCIENCE INST BERKELEY CA, 2004.
- (3) Shriberg, E., et al., “[The ICSI Meeting Recorder Dialog Act
  (MRDA) Corpus](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=5772938544285889197&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)” Proc. SIGDIAL, Cambridge, MA, April-May 2004.